# How do I make a sunlight in space?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light

### I am Using Blender Cycles, blender version 2.79

My question is very simple, I want a Sun dot light as those images :

[image]
[image]

I knew a way , But it was very **hard** and **Complicated** . So what i want is to achieve the nearest look of the **sun only** with a simple nodes or with a way that is not hard.

So Is there Any other way  ?

Comment: Easiest way is with Glare node in the compositor. What have you tried? What was hard and complicated about it? What renderer are you using? (Blender Internal ot Cycles?)

Comment: @cegaton  I am using Blender Cycles, Actually I Used the way in Blender guru Video - Which is very complicated - [How to make earth in cycles][https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/earth-cycles] 40:00 time.Sorry , But i don't know the name of the way.What i know that he is using blur effects an  ID masks and others ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a very simplified effect:

On your sun object use an emission shader and use a large value.

The glare can be created in the compositor using a glare node. Here I combined streaks and Fog Glow.

The threshold value determines the brightness at which the glare will start affecting the picture.

Then composite that over a background image.

[image]

(click on the image to enlarge)